# How can I remove the default empty buffer from vim?

Tags: vim

Whenever I work with multiple buffers, there is always one empty. I would like to not have that if I open a file with vim from the command line (i.e. I don't want to create a new file, or choose to create a new file by naming it first and starting vim with that name). How can I do this?

**Edit**:

I'm launching gvim the following way:

I have an alias in my bashrc: `alias g="gvim --remote-silent"`

I open files from the command line with: `g name-of-file`

At this point (if I didn't already have an instance of gvim open), I have two buffers:

[image]

**Edit2**:

Platform is Linux Mint, version is: VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Mar 24 2011 07:07:39).

I updated my NERDTree plugin as David suggested, but it didn't help. Other plugins I use: Pathogen, a,               doxygentoolkit,  nerdtree,  snipmate,              vim-rails,
ack_plugin,      easymotion,      protobuf,  sparkup,               yankring,
bufexplorer,     matchit,         rainbow,   surround,
clang_complete,  nerdcommenter,   repeat

Comment: When you pass vim a file on the command line, you don’t get an empty buffer. Same as if you open vim and `:e foo`. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Yep. We apparently don't have your problem.Please tell us how you launch vim (what version/OS) and how you open files

Comment: Thanks, I added more information.

Comment: Do you have the NERD tree installed?  I had this problem with an older version of the NERD tree.  Upgrading to the latest version solved it for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have your problem on

- linux, gvim - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Mar 24 2011 07:07:34) Included patches: 1-35
- windows gvim - Vi IMproved 7.2 (2008 Aug 9, compiled Aug  9 2008 18:46:22) MS-Windows 32-bit GUI version with OLE support

You are probably looking at a bug.

You might be able to debug things by cleaning your $MYVIMRC (temporarily) and running gvim `--noplugin`.

Alternatively inspect all settings (like `bufhidden` and other suspect parties)

```
 :set
 :setglobal
```

and see from which script/plugin they are being set (**`bufhidden` as an *example* only here**):

```
 :verbose set bufhidden
 :verbose setglobal bufhidden
```

You might also inspect autocommands (that might prevent buffers from being wiped)

```
 :verbose au
```

Comment: This must be one of my plugins. I wanted to reorganize them and maybe move to vundle from pathogen, so I'll do this now and get back with the cause. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks sehe. I have replaced my old pathogen setup with vundle and all of my plugins were updated. I left out some of which I didn't use. In case anyone has the same problem, I suggest checking those plugins I listed in my question. I didn't take the time to corner the one causing it, especially since there is no guarantee it was only one of them. Anyway, Vundle is nice, my updated plugins are nice, life is good :)

Answer (score 2):

To avoid this I changed my alias:

```
g() { [ -z "$(command gvim --serverlist)" ] && command gvim "$@" || command gvim --remote-silent "$@" ; }
```

If the list of server is empty: launch plain gvim, otherwise launch with remote-silent option.